# How to detect that bpftrace has attached its probes and is ready to trace?

Tags: linux, trace, ebpf, bpftrace

I working with `bpftrace` scripts attaching to hundreds of probes and sometimes it takes a couple of seconds or minutes for `bpftrace` to start tracing. This is not an issue if I'm providing the command via `-c` because the command starts when the tracer is ready. In general, however, I'd like to know if there is a way detect that the `bpftrace` program is ready to trace. I'd like to run my command outside of `bpftrace` (i.e., without using `-c`) but for that I need to be sure that `bpftrace` is ready.